# Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--httpinterface' (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb

Based in this guide:

https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/install-simple-test-deployment/

I am installing MongoDB. This works fine but when I try to run it with: `--httpinterface` like:

```
sudo -u mongod mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/appdb \
  --logpath /data/appdb/mongodb.log \
  --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 1 --fork \
  --httpinterface
```

I get:

```
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--httpinterface'
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

Enabling `httpinterface` is described here:
https://ademirgabardo.wordpress.com/2016/02/07/how-to-access-http-interface-mongodb/

and I also tried to add it to `/etc/mongod.conf`:

```
httpinterface=true
rest=true
```

And then restart mongod with the above options but same result. I also tried to add it in `/etc/mongod.conf` like:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.
  http:
    enabled: true
    RESTInterfaceEnabled: true
```

Any suggestions on how to enable http interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#http-interface-and-rest-api:

> MongoDB 3.6 removes the deprecated HTTP interface and REST API to MongoDB

Either downgrade to 3.4 (it's still supported till January 2020) or user 3rd party tools, e.g. listed in https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/

Comment: Oh so there is not way of enabling that 4.0? I don't really want to downgrade just for this.

Comment: Very wise of you. I have updated the answer with better alternative.